# Image upload From React Native not working but postman working

Tags: laravel, api, react-native

```
 if ($request->hasFile('avatar')) {
            return "HEllo One";
            $fileNameToStore =  time() . '.' . $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileNameToStore, fopen($request->file('avatar'), 'r+', 'public'));

            $getImageUlr = Storage::disk('s3')->url($fileNameToStore);
            return $getImageUlr;
        }
        return "HEllo two";
```

Always return Hello two  can not enter when has image inside if condition is laravel code problem or react native problem bit confuse so please help !

Answer (score 0):

The first `return` always exits the function/procedure you're in. The code below the `return` inside the `if`'s body will never get executed.